# How to add your own movies to Zune's TV/Music/Movies categories?

Tags: video, zune-software

In the Zune 4.2 software, is there a way to add your own videos to the **TV**, **Music** and **Movies** categories? Right now my entire video collection is placed as Other.

I assume that videos you purchase from online services get categorised into those groups, but is there a way to make your own videos do this? Perhaps through the use of tags or specific folders?

*Note: I live in a non-Zune supported country so I have no access to the online services.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, I have done it myself...

Find the video you want to change, right-click it and select `Edit`.  A window comes up:

[image]

As you can see, you can *select from TV, Movies, Music, Personal, & Other.*  Hope that helps!